# How to store Birthdate and Age so that Age can be updated daily in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date

**How should I store Birthdate's in MySQL so that I can easily update everyone's Age on a daily basis via a Cron Job?**

Does it even make sense to store the Age AND the Birthdate so that when searches involving the Age are made, I don't have to calculate each Age on-the-fly and waste CPU resources?

If so, how should I 1) store the Birthdate, and 2) calculate the Age each day?

I can imagine the daily cron script first filtering out the user's whose Birthdate month is not the current month, then filtering out the user's whose Birthdate day is not the current day, and then incrementing by one the age of each user that is left.

Does this make sense?  If so, how would I do that?  Is there a better way to do all of this?

Comment: Have you tried looking into views?

Comment: @mellamokb:  No, I'm not familiar with that.  Can you please send me a link where I can learn about it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simple answer is don't; never store a persons age. It changes for each person yearly but, as you say, you have to check that it's correct for every person daily.

Only store the date of birth, and then calculate the age when selecting from the database. It's only `today - date of birth` so takes almost no CPUs at all.

EDIT:

To expand upon my comment in [ManseUK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788741/458741) there's also the possibility of failure. What happens if your server / database is down? Or your update fails to run at its specified time? Or someone comes along and runs it manually after the update already been run for that date? Or someone turns off your scheduler? There's no danger of this happening if you calculate `Age` as you select from the database.

To select where age is between 25 and 30 years and assuming a DATE column `dateofbirth` your query would be something like:

```
select *
  from users
 where dateofbirth between date_add( curdate(), interval -30 year )
                       and date_add( curdate(), interval -25 year )
```

Ensure `users` is indexed on `dateofbirth`.

Comment: But what if you have millions of users and wanted to find out all the ones whose Age is greater than 25 but less than 30?  Wouldn't it have to calculate the Age of millions of users on-the-fly in order to do that search?  That sounds very inefficient compared to a once-a-day update and then simply indexing the Age column.  Can you please clarify?  Thanks.

Comment: @Programmer, if you have millions of users then your age calculation each day becomes ever more horrible. If you want to do this, then create an index on dob and craft your query in a way to use this index. `where dob between today - 30 yrs and today - 25 yrs`

Comment: @Ben the leap year problem is the same if using PHP or MySQL or any other language .....

Comment: @Ben:  Thanks for the clarification.  But can you please edit your post to explain this part:  "It's only today - date of birth" ?  Please use an example (with datatypes) as I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.  In other words, how would I store it and how would I do a search query where Age > 25 and < 30 using your solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, don't store age, just calculate it in your queries. As for the birthday, I prefer to have all my date/time in unix timestamps (because I hate to deal with portability across date-format-changing locale settings)

Comment: But what if you have millions of users and wanted to find out all the ones whose Age is greater than 25 but less than 30?  Wouldn't it have to calculate the Age of millions of users on-the-fly in order to do that search?  That sounds very inefficient compared to a once-a-day update and then simply indexing the Age column.  Can you please clarify?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it even make sense to store the Age

No.

> I don't have to calculate each Age on-the-fly and waste CPU resources?

As a matter of fact, you'd waste a zillion more "CPU resources" (of which you have too vague idea to be concerned of) with your everyday update approach.

> Is there a better way to do all of this?

Store the birthdate and calculate the age at select time

> what if you want to find out all the ones whose Age is greater than 25 but less than 30?

this is quite trivial query like this

```
WHERE birth_date BETWEEN date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR) 
                     AND date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
```

the query would using an index (if any) and thus be blazing fast, without any [unnecessary] denormalizations

Comment: But what if you have millions of users and wanted to find out all the ones whose Age is greater than 25 but less than 30?  Wouldn't it have to calculate the Age of millions of users on-the-fly in order to do that search?  That sounds very inefficient compared to a once-a-day update and then simply indexing the Age column.  Can you please clarify?  Thanks.

Comment: finding an age is no more difficult operation than finding all females or all persons with Ph.D. degree. it's quite trivial task for the database. the problem with both questions and answers on this site - they are all from the *imaginary world*, not the real one. "simple indexing" you are talking about is a **heavy disk operation** to update and reindex all the billions users ages.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification.  So how should I sotre the birthdate, and how would I calculate the age at select time (especially when doing a search for Age > 25 and Age < 30, for example) ?  Thanks!

Comment: just added the query example :)

Comment: Thanks!  So would you store birth_date as type "DATE" ?  I never worked with that data type, but based on your example, it looks pretty straightforward and even natural for MySQL.

Comment: Sure, that's what I am talking about. Such calculations are indeed natural for the database. And yes, this query assuming the birth date stored as DATE type - the most natural type for storing dates.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to go against <strike>the majority</strike> all of the answers here.

I would store both ...

- updating the age is quick and simple - a single mysql query could run every day and its done
- calculating the age is time consuming when you have lots of page views - amount of times its viewed far outweighs the number of changes

Just imagine a table scenario - a table with 100 or 1000 rows that shows the age of a person ... how long is that going to take to compute ???

I always thought that Stackoverflow calculated the Reputation dynamically but you can see on the [Stackoverflow data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) that they dont - see the User object in the schema on the right. Its recorded and updated each time its changed - I would guess that this is purely because of the amount of times its viewed far outweighs the number of changes

Comment: :-( I was waiting for the downvote .... but Im going to stand by my answer ... until someone convinces me otherwise :-)

Comment: A table that shows 1000 rows will take an age... to render in the browser.

Comment: @YourCommonSense your right !! it probably would !! then say its a table of 10 rows and 1000 concurrent users .... a downvote from you would be easier to take (if it was you?) than someone who just clicked the down vote because i have a different opinion

Comment: disclaimer: I didn't downvote (disagreeing isn't a reason to do so). Calculating the age on exit is hardly more time consuming than `2 - 1`, definitely nothing compared to an update. It's also certain. If an update fails (server is down) your data is wrong, unlike with calculating it dynamically.

Comment: I'd cache an age then, *along with other data* from that table. That's how things done in the *real world*.

Comment: @Ben if the server is down i would like to see how its going to calcuate dynamically .... the update would happen once ... at midnight ...

Comment: I'm not the down voter and I wouldn't rule out having an age column especially if it was something that was often queried.  However, I think your update is a bit fragile.  If a day was skipped or if the update was run twice then there would be issues.  If I was going with this approach then I would recalc everyone's age and update if changed.

Comment: @ManseUK, of course it won't; but it will be correct when you next select it ( as there's no external operation to rely on).

Comment: @Ben a MySQL query is hardly an "External operation" its a just a query ... and the fact thats its run or not its trivial to resolve ... perhaps the best of both - if the "age update process" hasnt run then calculate

Comment: @ManseUK: interesting post as this is also what I initially thought.  Because what if you have millions of users and wanted to find out all the ones whose Age is greater than 25 but less than 30?  If you calculate it dynamically, wouldn't it have to calculate the Age of millions of users on-the-fly in order to do that search?  That sounds very inefficient compared to a once-a-day update and then simply indexing the Age column.  By the way, what's "CURDATE()" and how would you store DOB in your example?  Thanks.

Comment: @Programmer [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) is a function in MySQL to retrieve the current date ... I would use the `DATE` datatype to store a date

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's totally true that computing age dynamically takes a lot of memory. 
Why not create a table CALENDAR with 365 rows 1 row for each day of an year. And store a list of userid against the day corresponding to their birthday.
For each day just refer the table  entry for that day and refresh the age of only those selected users.
This will reduce the complexity greatly even when the user base increases.