# How to find users aged between 25 and 30 when the birthdates are stored as type "date" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I've been informed on SO [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788542/how-to-store-birthdate-and-age-so-that-age-can-be-updated-daily-in-php-mysql) that the correct way to do this would be:

```
WHERE birth_date BETWEEN date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR) 
                     AND date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
```

However, this does not actually include users who are older than 30 and younger than 31.  When we commonly speak of people's ages, we take someone who is 30 years and 11 months old to still be "30".

With that in mind, simply making the second interval `31` (one year more than you intend) would seem like an obvious solution, but that includes users who turned 31 today, so it's no good.

So what is the **definitive** and **fastest** way to find users whose ages are **greater than or equal** to 25 and **less** than 31 when the birthdates are stored as type `date` in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to switch the two dates add another day to the first date, like this:

```
WHERE birth_date 
BETWEEN 
    date_add(
        date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 31 YEAR), 
        INTERVAL 1 DAY
    )
AND date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR)
```

Looking at the other proposed answer, actually there is a simpler solution.

```
WHERE birth_date <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR) 
      AND birth_date > date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 31 YEAR)
```

Note the `>` on the second comparison, that saves adding the 1 DAY interval, but you still need to use 31 YEARs, not 30. The `BETWEEN AND` expression will do `>=` and `<=`.

(Please accept his answer when it proves to be correct and he/you edited the comparison and changed the 30 to 31- he pointed me in the right direction)

Comment: Interesting!  What is that doing exactly?

Comment: its just subtracting another day. Wait, it should actually add it. Will edit answer.

Comment: Your edited answer does not seem to be working.  It's not returning any results.

Comment: I guess I'm getting tired. I didn't notice that your initial query was the wrong way round... here goes *another* edit...

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use `BETWEEN` for dates when a normal comparison will do, especially with that weird edge behavior.

```
WHERE birth_date <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR) 
      AND birth_date >= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
```

Comment: Isn't the code you posted the same thing as using `BETWEEN` since you are using `<=` and `>=`?  Won't that have the same problem I posted about above?

Comment: @Programmer Well I just tried running it using `'1983-03-09'` as `birth_date` and it seemed to work, so I don't know